# launch fragment by variable name

Tags: android, android-fragments

I was wondering if it was possible to launch a `fragment` by `variable` name rather then hard coding the `fragments` name.

Allow me to post a sample

This is how you traditionally launch a fragment:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.your_placehodler, new YourFragment());
ft.commit();
```

But say you are trying to launch the `fragment` without knowing the name of it, or possibly which `fragment` it is. Say like a `listFragment`, or a `Listview` and you are running through an `array` of `Fragment` names. Hence you would do something like this:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

     private String[] values = new String[] { "frag1", "frag2", "frag3" };

     String someFragment = values[position];
     String fragName = (someFragment + ".class");

     try {
     FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
     ft.replace(R.id.your_placehodler, new fragName());
     ft.commit();
     } catch (Exception e) {
     //print message
     }
```

I know this is not correct, but I feel like if it's possible I may be close. I searched for a while but I found nothing.

So my question, Is this possible? If so how would I implement it? Thanks!

**Edit**
I attempted what I thought may work with the Reflections API using this code

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    String questions = values[position];

    try {
        Fragment frags = (Fragment) Class.forName("com.example.android." + questions).newInstance();            
        getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in,
                        android.R.animator.fade_out)
                .replace(R.id.header_fragment_container, frags).commit();

    }

    catch (Exception e) {

    }

}
}
```

I get a message saying
`05-08 04:38:14.124: W/dalvikvm(812): dvmFindClassByName rejecting 'com.android.example.Ovens'`

Yet if in my code I change the line to say 
`Fragment frags = (Fragment) Class.forName("com.android.example." + "Ovens").newInstance();`

It works

The variable "questions" is an exact copy of the class name. I don't see why it wouldn't work. Nothing happens, nothing prints to the logcat

**Final Edit**

Got it! I was missing the "" marker. Here is the final working code, thanks for all the help

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    String questions = values[position];
    try {
        Fragment frags = (Fragment) Class.forName("com.android.example." + "" + questions).newInstance();
        getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in,
                        android.R.animator.fade_out)
                .replace(R.id.header_fragment_container, frags).commit();
    }

    catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what problem your are trying to solve with this technique? In particular, why do you want to do this in the first place? I ask because I believe there are likely other ways to solve your original problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to acheive this is through the reflection APIs.

```
Class.forName("com.example.MyFragment").newInstance();
```

This can throw a whole host of Exceptions so look out for that.

Another way would be to create a simple factory class for your Fragments.

```
public abstract class MyFragmentFactory {
    private MyFragmentFactory(){}

    public static <T extends Fragment> T getFragment(String name){
        if("MyFragment".equals(name)){
            return new MyFragment();
        }else if("whatever".equals(name)){
            // ...
        }else{
            throw new RuntimeException("unknown fragment "+ name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would want to accomplish this through something similar to reflection API's. I will edit the post above to show what I mean. However will this work for fragments? Because I thought the Class.forName("packagename" + variable) would only work for Activity's.

Comment: You need to use the full name of the Fragment in forName(). Activities and Fragments are both just normal Java classes.

Comment: add Log.d("tag", "", e); to the catch block

Comment: the names in values should be in the form 'com.example.Ovens'. You need the full class name.

Comment: OMG I figured it out. It needed a "" + questions! So stupid... I will show a final edit with the finished working code

Answer (score 8):

Probably too late to answer but putting here for others. Instead of using

```
 Fragment frags = (Fragment) Class.forName("com.android.example." + "" + questions).newInstance();
```

use

```
Fragment frags = Fragment.instantiate(mContext,"com.android.example." + "" + questions);
```

and if you want to pass arguments to the fragment you can use

```
Fragment frags = Fragment.instantiate(mContext,"com.android.example." + "" + questions,bundle);
```

where bundle is the Bundle carrying your data.

**Edit:**

As to why you should prefer this over other:

1. You can send Bundle args to you fragment
2. caching using sClassMap
3. Sanity checks for whether the class initialized is fragment or not

Here is the code for instantiate method in fragment

```
public static Fragment instantiate(Context context, String fname, @Nullable Bundle args) {
        try {
            Class<?> clazz = sClassMap.get(fname);
            if (clazz == null) {
                // Class not found in the cache, see if it's real, and try to add it
                clazz = context.getClassLoader().loadClass(fname);
                if (!Fragment.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
                    throw new InstantiationException("Trying to instantiate a class " + fname
                            + " that is not a Fragment", new ClassCastException());
                }
                sClassMap.put(fname, clazz);
            }
            Fragment f = (Fragment)clazz.newInstance();
            if (args != null) {
                args.setClassLoader(f.getClass().getClassLoader());
                f.mArguments = args;
            }
            return f;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new InstantiationException("Unable to instantiate fragment " + fname
                    + ": make sure class name exists, is public, and has an"
                    + " empty constructor that is public", e);
        } catch (java.lang.InstantiationException e) {
            throw new InstantiationException("Unable to instantiate fragment " + fname
                    + ": make sure class name exists, is public, and has an"
                    + " empty constructor that is public", e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new InstantiationException("Unable to instantiate fragment " + fname
                    + ": make sure class name exists, is public, and has an"
                    + " empty constructor that is public", e);
        }
    }
```

where sClassMap is a HashMap

```
private static final HashMap<String, Class<?>> sClassMap =
        new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();
```

obviously you can implement the same feature in above code. Reason not to do so ["DRY"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: Is there a reason why one would prefer this approach (Fragment.instantiate) instead of Class.forName?

Comment: Hope the edit clears your question. If you have any question feel free to ask

Comment: @ichalos It is soooooooo much cleaner. One line in Android vs a "try" with about ten "catches"